# Are there any issues with allowing the KLMS Agent app (part of Samsung KNOX) to be restricted by Data Saver?

Tags: samsung, security, battery, background-data, samsung-knox

I use the "Data Saver" feature to extend battery life and to prevent/reduce apps from accessing the internet when the phone/tablet is sleeping and when they are not supposed to be running.  Note that I'm not sure if that feature is an Android or OEM feature.

To accomplish this, I go to:
`Settings` > `Apps` > `Special Access` > `Allow app while Data Saver on` > `Show system apps`

and deselect every app... currently with the sole exception of `KLMS Agent`.

The only reason I do not deselect `KLMS Agent` is because I do not fully understand its purpose, and if there are any consequences of preventing it from being "allowed" while Data Saver is on.

From what I've researched, `KLMS Agent` is part of KNOX security, which is pre-installed on most (all?) Samsung Android devices.  I've read a bit about KNOX, and I've never had the time to fully understand all of the details about it.  Plus, I think it's closed-source, which makes it almost impossible to truly fully understand.

Are there any downsides or issues with ***deselecting*** `KLMS Agent` in the `Allow app while Data Saver on` list, thus allowing `KLMS Agent` to be restricted by Data Saver?